# Does dropping rank affect your diehard rank?

Tags: diehard-dungeon

If I 'drop rank' (using the option on the 'stats' screen, not by dying or other ways that cause you to lose rank), will it affect my place on the diehard leaderboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

http://steamcommunity.com/app/277870/discussions/0/540737414870758326/

a quote from the developer:

> Hi, once you've reached diehard rank, your diehard points will remain,
>   even if you drop rank. It just means that you won't continue to
>   accumulate diehard points until you reach diehard rank again.